How do I pass a null value to one of the parameters of retrofit body
I have a request body
{
   "userName":"xyz",
   "teamAssigned":null
}

and suppose this is stored in a serializable object in kotlin, xyzApiRequestBody, now when I pass this to my retrofit body, the key "teamAssigned" is removed from the serialized request, only the keys whose value is not null is passed to API.
I want to know how to do this .
I have added serializeNulls() in my GsonBuilder passed to addConverterFactory.

I would pass a nullable variable (say, val team : String?) and assign it's value to null as and when needed. Or, is the issue related to Retrofit not sending the key with null as it's value?

The answer will depend on what serialization library you’re using.
